# How do I extract CAN Error frames from a blf file using python-can package

Tags: python, can-bus

I am using python-can to read my blf file. When i decode the file using a commercial program I see CAN Error (Stuff Error).

When I read the data using python-can i only see the valid messages.

Using the code below:

```
import can
can_log = can.BLFReader(filename)
for msg in can_log:
    print(msg)
```

I only get messages with no errors... (is_error_frame flag was always false). Nether the less I know that there are "Stuff Error" information messages.

How could I read those massages as well?

Comment: Although I cannot provide you a working code solution here, I can give you a helpful point: 
blf logging does not considers Error messages as CAN messages. In fact, neither CAN protocol considers an error flag a message. 
Therefore, your for msg will parse only the message objects, and will skip the error flags. 
If you don't have a class for error flags, I fear the only solution is to regex extract your blf. 

Also, error_state_indicator is not part of the CAN protocol message format, it is meta data of Vector/blf logs.